# Turning validations off for mass data update in sandbox

Tags: apex, sandbox, update

I do mass updates in sandbox and i dont want to trigger any automations or validations so is there a way (maybe using apex code) to turn off all validations and automations like flow,trigger,etc?

Comment: There are tools that can do this for you, like https://cloudtoolkit.co

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no single place where you can disable all automations at once. You can deactivate triggers/Flows/PBs and validation rules before starting the data load in your Sandbox.

If you are doing this frequently, a best alternative is to build this "by pass automation" feature using custom settings. Include this custom setting in all your automation logic. Set to TRUE when you want to bypass the triggers, validation rules and workflow. Then, you have to ckeck the value of this field for every component you want to allow the bypass.

Some examples:

https://www.infallibletechie.com/2018/10/how-to-bypass-all-triggers-validation.html

https://www.asagarwal.com/how-to-bypass-automations-validations-in-salesforce-for-mass-dml-operations/